# Why would a cross-compiled DLL export symbols already defined in MSVCRT?

Tags: mingw-w64, mxe

I'm using [MXE](https://mxe.cc/) to build my own cross-compiler toolchain ([this specific version](https://github.com/mxe/mxe/tree/6d90c4ce068be5312d762f1a5e6a64d610e0e8ca)). Only I don't use the default gcc 5.5 but gcc 6.3.0 instead.

I'm not specifically tied to that version - I just picked it because it was also used to [generate the latest portaudio binaries](https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries)

It appears that for some reason, some MSVCRT symbols have been included in and are exported by the portaudio DLL:

`dumpbin /exports libportaudio64bit.dll`

```
    992  3DF 00032F30 mbrlen
    993  3E0 00032D90 mbrtowc
    994  3E1 00032E00 mbsrtowcs
   1112  457 00033180 wcrtomb
   1113  458 000331C0 wcsrtombs
```

I only found out because I was trying to cross-compile and build [bzip2 1.0.8](https://www.sourceware.org/bzip2/)
This is pretty old and it doesn't have all the infrastructure in place to support cross-compiling. However it can be done by hand in a couple of very simple steps:

```
   make CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-gcc AR=x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-ar RANLIB=x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-ranlib libbz2.a 
   x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-gcc *.o -s -shared -o libbz2-1.dll
```

Alike the portaudio DLLs, the above exports the same symbols:

`dumpbin /exports libbz2-1.dll`

```
     36   23 00012B60 mbrlen
     37   24 000129F0 mbrtowc
     38   25 00012A60 mbsrtowcs
     39   26 00012DC0 wcrtomb
     40   27 00012E00 wcsrtombs
```

Needless to say, this is causing issues at link time, due to multiple definitions of the same symbol (`mingw-w64-v8.0.0/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mbrtowc.c:98: multiple definition of 'mbrtowc' - x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a(lib64_libmsvcrt_os_a-mbrtowc.o): first defined here`)

My question is not how to avoid this issue. That can be done by using a DEF file when building the DLLs, to control the exact list of exported functions.

My question is more fundamental: why would these symbols be exported in the first place ? Is this a bug somewhere ?

Comment: Why gcc 6.3.0? That's a version from 2016, current gcc version is 11.2.0. Also current MinGW-w64 version is 9.0.0.

Comment: Well the industry is sometimes a bit slow to adopt new tools and often prefers (for better or worse) old and trusted ways... Most tools I work with only support (officially at least) gcc 6.3.0 (e.g. [matlab 2020a](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/system-requirements-release-2020a-supported-compilers.pdf) or hardware simulation tools from Cadence and Synopsys). As I said, I know to avoid the issue, but I'm trying to learn: are my expectations incorrect, is there something in the linking strategy that I don't understand ? or just a bug ?

Comment: I don't know why your libraries export standard library functions. Have you tried ignoring the issue by linking with `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition` ?

Comment: I didn't try that but I'm quite sure it would avoid the issue. As I said, my question is not how to avoid the issue though, but why it's happening. Is there a bug in MinGW-w64 8.0.0 and/or in gcc 6.3.0 ? Has this bug been clearly identified and explicitly fixed ? or is it still there in MinGW-w64 9.0.0 and/or in gcc 11.2.0 ?